# How to display an instance of a certain keyword in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

```
data <- data.frame(Row1= c("Action 1", "Action 2", "Action 3"),
                  Row2= c("The dog walked", "The cat jumped", "The dog slept"))
```

Is it possible to display all the instances where a certain keyword is found? In this example data frame, I want to return all instances where the word dog is present, as well as their corresponding rows.

The example output for this would be:

```
"Action 1: The dog walked"
"Action 3: The dog slept"
```

I have done a little background research on functions such as grep() thinking that may be applicable here.

Answer (score 0):

```
> data[grep("dog", data$Row2), ]
      Row1           Row2
1 Action 1 The dog walked
3 Action 3  The dog slept
```

Alternative:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  filter(grepl("dog", Row2)) %>% 
  mutate(output = paste(Row1, ":", Row2)) %>% 
  select(output)
                     output
1 Action 1 : The dog walked
2 Action 3 : The dog slept
```